# Can't read an enum type .name() into a jsp: uncaught reference error

Tags: java, jsp

This is my java class:

```
package org.at.network;

public class MyClass {

public static enum Type {
    ROOT(0),RELAY(1),LEAF(2),NULL(3);

    private int value;

    Type(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
 ....
```

Now in my jsp:

```
<%@page import="org.at.network.MyClass"%>

var ROOT = <%=MyClass.Type.ROOT.name() %>;
```

How come it gives me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ROOT is not defined

?

If I execute that code in a java class it works so it should be a jsp problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a javascript problem...

Probalby the javascript code that is generated looks like this:

```
var ROOT = ROOT;
```

so at this point the variable `ROOT` is undefined.

You probably wanted to save it as string:

so try doing:

```
var ROOT = '<%=MyClass.Type.ROOT.name() %>';
```

doing so the js code generated will be

```
var ROOT = 'ROOT';
```

Answer (score 0):

use getValue() method instead of getName() method